# UITableView is crashing if I call `insertRows` while rotating the device "Incorrect checksum for freed object"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, malloc

I have to parse a lot of data to display in my Tableview.

So, instead of parsing all the data and then reload the table view, I end up with parsing 50 rows of data and insert them.

So, the user has something to see right away and while I keep parsing the rest of the data and insert 50 more each time.

This works perfectly if I don't rotate the device but if I rotate while this is still adding data, my app crashes.

Here's me adding the data and checking if 50 rows of data have been added:

```
self.comments.append(currentComment)

indexPathsToAdd.append(IndexPath(row: self.comments.count - 1, section: 1))

if self.comments.count % 50 == 0 {
    self.addRowsIfNeeded(indexPathsToAdd: indexPathsToAdd)
    indexPathsToAdd.removeAll()
}
```

Here's how I insert the rows:

```
func addRowsIfNeeded( indexPathsToAdd : [IndexPath]){
        if indexPathsToAdd.count > 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
                self.myTableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsToAdd, with: .fade)
                self.myTableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
```

The error message is usually:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[APPNAME.GodTableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3698.84.15/UITableView.m:2055 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (150) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (127), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (50 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

But sometimes I also get this weird error which I have no idea what it means:

**malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x1509c7000: probably modified after being freed. Corrupt value: 0x71**

Comment: (1)UITableview's reload method called  when the device is being rotated?

Comment: @Merl I don't have reloadData for the tableview anywhere. I am only using `self.myTableView.insertRows` to add rows. I have also not implemented `viewWillTransition` or `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` etc so I am not touching the tableview myself to reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are updating your data source array `self.comments` but not inserting the rows until you have inserted 50 additional comments.  Presumably your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `self.comments.count`.

Let's say that before you start inserting rows, the array has 100 elements.

When you rotate the device it causes the tableview to reload, calling `numberOfRowsInSection` - The number of rows that are returned includes rows that you have added to the array, but for which you have not yet called `insertRows`.  This then becomes the new count for the number of rows in the table view (From your exception message, this is 127).

When you finally call `insertRows` you get an exception because the table view thinks you should have `127+50 = 177` rows, but the array only contains `100+50 = 150`.

I suggest that you add the new comments to a temporary array until you are ready to actually insert the rows.  That way `numberOfRowsInSection` will return the correct number:

```
var newComments = [Comment]()
var indexPathsToAdd = [IndexPath]()

// ...

newComments.append(currentComment)

indexPathsToAdd.append(IndexPath(row: self.comments.count + newComments.count - 1, section: 1))

if newComments.count % 50 == 0 {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
        self.comments.append(contentsOf:newComments)
        self.myTableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsToAdd, with: .fade)
        self.myTableView.endUpdates()
    }
    newComments.removeAll()
    indexPathsToAdd.removeAll()
}
```

Comment: Yep, this sounds like the problem I am having. Is tableview supposed to call `reloadData` internally when rotation happens? I don't remember reading this behavior in the documentation but it does seem like what it's doing. I will try this way and report back but I have confidence this might work. Will report back!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! This worked great! Only thing I did have to change was to insert IndexPath using sum of the original comments array and the new comments and use the new comments array for checking % 50.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a capture list for `indexPathsToAdd` in the closure

```
    func addRowsIfNeeded( indexPathsToAdd : [IndexPath]){ 
        if indexPathsToAdd.count > 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              [indexPathsToAdd] in
                self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
                self.myTableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsToAdd, with: .fade)
                self.myTableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
```